# What is the function of Daniels' ribbed suit?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

In several episodes, such as ENT: "Azati Prime", Agent Daniels is wearing a ribbed suit that reminds me of the Dune stillsuits designed for cooling. It also has no rank or affiliation marks. What is this suit's function? It looks very uncomfortable.

[image: Agent Daniels' ribbed suit]

Comment: @ThePopMachine, it is entirely possible that the purpose of the suit is explained in some Trek novel or another. So the question looks reasonable to me.

Comment: @o.m. -  might be better asked "*does* the suit have any function other than simply being a uniform?" Otherwise, we might ask the same thing about every uniform ever worn on any episode by any race, when there really isn't much reason to think there is a function beyond standard uniform attire

Comment: Just for the record, I don't object to the question and I didn't downvote.   However, my first comment is very likely the answer, and my second comment is just a joke.

Comment: The other most likely answer in my opinion is that they intended it to be some sort of time-travel protective gear, inspired by an air fighter [Pressure Suit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_suit).

Comment: In following the franchise it would be very unlike the Federation to put members in garments just for show. The Terran Empire did this, Klingons did this, but Federation uniforms have always put practicality first. Daniels' seems to break from what we expect and have seen.

Comment: "Federation uniforms have always put practicality first" Citation needed! I'm pretty sure Picard would also object, see the infamous Picard maneuver/shirt tug.

Comment: @Rebel-Scum also see any of the female uniforms in TOS and early TNG.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Being a suite from a future thousand-year civilization, I believe producers were assertive asking costume department for a suite design that make audience like you, to ask that sort of questions about it.

Comment: I think usually when they invest that kind of energy, they also tease the audience with an answer somewhere - "Stay tuned!".